# conditionally render siteUrl property in Gatsby-config based on environment

Tags: gatsby

I would like to set up a simple expression in my `gatsby-config.js` that determines whether I am working locally or in production so that I can set the `siteUrl` property appropriately.

My gatsby-config *(with psuedo code)*:

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: "My title",
        description: "My description...",
        siteUrl: (process.env=DEVELOPMENT) ? "/" : "https://example.com /* something here */
  }, {
     ... 
  }
```

Is this possible with simple JS, string literals, etc.. ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've found the solution to my problem (along with a couple of gotchas).

The first distinction I had to make was between OS vars and project vars, as per the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#accessing-environment-variables-in-javascript). I wasn't too clear on that but decided that my root URL was a project environment variable as it changed depending on whether I was in production or development.

That said, I only needed to define my URLs in their respective `.env` files:

```
// .env.development
SITE_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

**N.B**: You have to define the HTTP protocol on localhost, otherwise you'll run into an `unhandled rejection, invalid URL` error with `Gatsby link`. I found it has to be HTTP to work.

```
// .env.production
SITE_URL=https://myproductionsite.com
```

Next, in my `gatsby-config.js`, I had to include the `dotenv` package at the top (as also noted in the Gatsby docs):

```
// gatsby-config.js
require("dotenv").config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

However, trying to spin up the gatsby development (or production) server, I kept running into a problem with `can't resolve 'fs' module`. I came to find this article from [Gatsby troubleshooting docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/troubleshooting-common-errors/#issues-with-fs-resolution) and added the following to my `gatsby-node.js` file to resolve it:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        node: {
            fs: "empty",
        },
    })
}
```

So ultimately, I was able to simply put the following in my `siteMetadata` section of the `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
// gatsby-config.js
require("dotenv").config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
siteMetadata: {
    title: "My Site",
    description: "My description...",
    ...
    siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,
    ...
```

This produces the desired behavior, calling up the proper SITE_URL variable based on environments.

Also note, this issue only happened when I included the property `siteUrl` in my `siteMetadata` object. If I could have taken it out I would have but am using it as a sitewide variable for SEO purposes and more.

**Gotcha**: If you're using Netlify you'll need to set up an Env Var in your build environment matching `SITE_URL` or else your build will break as the production variable won't work in the `gatsby-config` as is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, by setting up environment variables.

Create some `.env.*` files in root folder for different environments.

Docs here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set a `.env.development` and `.env.production`. Gatsby, by default, it will take the first one when you run a `gatsby develop` command and the second in `gatsby build`. Of course, you can change its behavior by changing your running script's command.

Once you set your `.env.development`, it should look like:

```
SITE_URL: https://www.google.com
```

Then, this variable will be exposed in any Gatsby's file in the runtime. You only need to access it by:

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: "My title",
        description: "My description...",
        siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL
  }, {
     ... 
  }
```

You can check the active environment by checking `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV` variable like:

```
siteUrl: process.env.GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV==='development' ? '/' : 'https://example.com'
```

You can change the default behavior by changing the running script in your package.json. For example:

```
"develop": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=whatever gatsby develop",
```

Now, `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV` would be `whatever` in a `develop` mode.

For further reading, check [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/)

Comment: Is `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV` a constant in Gatsby? It's not clear in the docs. When you say set a `.env` file, do you mean to create a file?

Comment: Yes, it's a constant in Gatsby, by default is `development` and `production` in `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` respectively. You can change its behavior by changing the running script. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @FerranBuireu this is not actually true: GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV is `undefined` if not explicitly set! (see my [pull request 'chore(docs): GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV is undefined by default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/31136) on this to correct the docs)...